# Change JPEG ColorSpace Encoding value

Tags: metadata, color-spaces, srgb, prophoto

I exported a photo to JPEG without realizing it had embedded Color Profile "ProPhoto RGB".  When I opened it in a viewer that, presumably, assumes the sRGB ColorSpace, I really liked the effect.

How can I modify the ColorSpace metadata value so that it is *always* rendered using sRGB?

And is there a less tricky way to achieve this conversion?  E.g., within Photoshop (or any other image editor) can I reproduce and then apply the effect of interpreting the existing image using different ColorSpace values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Adobe Photoshop, there are two menu options: "Assign Profile" and "Convert to Profile". If you have an image in the ProPhoto RGB color space, and you "assign profile" sRGB, this just changes the metadata in the file as to which colour space the RGB values refer to. It will give you the effect you want.

If you were to select "Convert to Profile", this would convert the image to the sRGB colour space, but retain (insofar as possible) the appearance of the colours in the image.

Comment: How can it be? If you **convert** an image to other color space how colors can remain unchanged? You **convert** it. Not just *change the metadata*, but execute a conversion. Don't you confuse these two option?

Comment: @Green when you "convert" from one colour space to another, essentially all the RGB values in the image are changing, but the editor is attempting to retain the appearance of the colours in the image using the new colour space, insofar as possible (i.e. RGB values are changed such that the value in the new colour space has the same appearance (if possible) as the old value does in the old colour space).